# Basics Of RBAC for Yii Framework

Tags: yii, rbac

I just set my RBAC hierarchie like this (using CPhpAuthManager)

```
                $auth = Yii::app()->authManager;

                $auth->createOperation('create', 'add new data');
                $auth->createOperation('read', 'read data');
                $auth->createOperation('update', 'update data');
                $auth->createOperation('delete', 'delete data');

                $teammember = $auth->createRole('teammember');
                $teammember->addChild('create');
                $teammember->addChild('read');
                $teammember->addChild('update');
                $teammember->addChild('delete');

                $auth->save();
```

And update my LoginForm model class like this :

```
    public function login()
    {
            if($this->_identity===null)
            {
                    $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
                    $this->_identity->authenticate();
            }
            if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
            {
                    $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
                    Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
                    ***Yii::app()->authManager->assign('teammember', Yii::app()->user->id);
                    return true;
            }
            else
                    return false;
    }
```

(Look at the line with **3 stars *****) (`Yii::app()->user->id` returns user's ID as integer)

It should work well. I'm logging user to system (`with Yii::app()->user->login()`) and then (`Yii::app()->authManager->assign()`)

Now i'm checking with this :

```
public function actionTest()
{
        if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('create'))
        {
                echo "YOU CAN DO THIS";
        }
        else
        {
                echo "YOU CAN'T DO THIS";
        }
}
```

But output is
**YOU CAN'T DO THIS** . Am i missing something? What is the problem?

**ADDITIONAL**

Result of

```
var_dump(Yii::app()->authManager->getRoles());
```

:

prettier version [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1637725/)

```
array(1) { ["teammember"]=> object(CAuthItem)#25 (8) { ["_auth":"CAuthItem":private]=> object(CPhpAuthManager)#20 (10) { ["authFile"]=> string(50) "/var/www/WingSplitDatabase/protected/data/auth.php" ["_items":"CPhpAuthManager":private]=> array(5) { ["create"]=> object(CAuthItem)#21 (8) { ["_auth":"CAuthItem":private]=> *RECURSION* ["_type":"CAuthItem":private]=> int(0) ["_name":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(6) "create" ["_description":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(12) "add new data" ["_bizRule":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_data":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_e":"CComponent":private]=> NULL ["_m":"CComponent":private]=> NULL } ["read"]=> object(CAuthItem)#22 (8) { ["_auth":"CAuthItem":private]=> *RECURSION* ["_type":"CAuthItem":private]=> int(0) ["_name":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(4) "read" ["_description":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(9) "read data" ["_bizRule":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_data":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_e":"CComponent":private]=> NULL ["_m":"CComponent":private]=> NULL } ["update"]=> object(CAuthItem)#23 (8) { ["_auth":"CAuthItem":private]=> *RECURSION* ["_type":"CAuthItem":private]=> int(0) ["_name":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(6) "update" ["_description":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(11) "update data" ["_bizRule":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_data":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_e":"CComponent":private]=> NULL ["_m":"CComponent":private]=> NULL } ["delete"]=> object(CAuthItem)#24 (8) { ["_auth":"CAuthItem":private]=> *RECURSION* ["_type":"CAuthItem":private]=> int(0) ["_name":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(6) "delete" ["_description":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(11) "delete data" ["_bizRule":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_data":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_e":"CComponent":private]=> NULL ["_m":"CComponent":private]=> NULL } ["teammember"]=> *RECURSION* } ["_children":"CPhpAuthManager":private]=> array(1) { ["teammember"]=> array(4) { ["create"]=> object(CAuthItem)#21 (8) { ["_auth":"CAuthItem":private]=> *RECURSION* ["_type":"CAuthItem":private]=> int(0) ["_name":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(6) "create" ["_description":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(12) "add new data" ["_bizRule":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_data":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_e":"CComponent":private]=> NULL ["_m":"CComponent":private]=> NULL } ["read"]=> object(CAuthItem)#22 (8) { ["_auth":"CAuthItem":private]=> *RECURSION* ["_type":"CAuthItem":private]=> int(0) ["_name":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(4) "read" ["_description":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(9) "read data" ["_bizRule":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_data":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_e":"CComponent":private]=> NULL ["_m":"CComponent":private]=> NULL } ["update"]=> object(CAuthItem)#23 (8) { ["_auth":"CAuthItem":private]=> *RECURSION* ["_type":"CAuthItem":private]=> int(0) ["_name":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(6) "update" ["_description":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(11) "update data" ["_bizRule":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_data":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_e":"CComponent":private]=> NULL ["_m":"CComponent":private]=> NULL } ["delete"]=> object(CAuthItem)#24 (8) { ["_auth":"CAuthItem":private]=> *RECURSION* ["_type":"CAuthItem":private]=> int(0) ["_name":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(6) "delete" ["_description":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(11) "delete data" ["_bizRule":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_data":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_e":"CComponent":private]=> NULL ["_m":"CComponent":private]=> NULL } } } ["_assignments":"CPhpAuthManager":private]=> array(0) { } ["showErrors"]=> bool(false) ["defaultRoles"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "ziyaretci" } ["behaviors"]=> array(0) { } ["_initialized":"CApplicationComponent":private]=> bool(true) ["_e":"CComponent":private]=> NULL ["_m":"CComponent":private]=> NULL } ["_type":"CAuthItem":private]=> int(2) ["_name":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(10) "teammember" ["_description":"CAuthItem":private]=> string(0) "" ["_bizRule":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_data":"CAuthItem":private]=> NULL ["_e":"CComponent":private]=> NULL ["_m":"CComponent":private]=> NULL } }
```

Comment: Downvote? really? why??!

Comment: Try adding `Yii::app()->authManager->save();` to the line after the line with 3 stars.

Comment: OMG it was really easy, i wasn't expecting this. @WillemRenzema please send this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any changes to your auth setup needs to be saved, so simply add the following line after your assignment:

`Yii::app()->authManager->save();`